# Problem with products image or view. Unable to see the product but when the cursor is hovered it appears

Tags: product, product-images, product-view

I am not able to see the product's image in the front end but when I hover the cursor over the product the image just slides in through  the left which looks very bad. Can any one please help me how to fix this problem?

http://www.bonappetit.co.in/

Scroll down to see the products.

Comment: did you use any product highlighter

Answer (score 0):

Check in admin product configuration, you might not have set the product image as thumbnail and base image options.If you will set both for a product image, it will be displayed properly.